# Validate input data from a DropDown depending of a DatePicker on another PartialView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, datepicker

I have some trouble with my ASP.NET MVC project.

I'm trying to check if the choice selected by a user in a *DropDown* is valid. This depends entirely of a date (chosen by the user) on another tab.

I have my **OfferController** which renders **FormView** (with **Offer** as a model). **FormView** contains 2 or 3 tabs, each one being a *PartialView* with it's own model.

I want to check a *DateTime* value entered on the first tab (**VehicleView** with **VehicleDetails** as model) to send an error message if needed on the second tab (**WarrantyView** with **Warranty** as model). This message has to be shown immediately when the user selects an incorrect item in the *DropDown*.

The model **Offer** contains both **VehicleDetails** and **Warranty**.

Others validations (using *annotations*) are working fine.

I've tried creating a *CustomValidator* as explained [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/creating-custom-validation-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc) but I couldn't get the updated value for the date from **VehicleDetails**.

I also tried to write some *JavaScript*, but as I've never done that before, I couldn't get far.

The date from the first tab:

```
@*[...]*@    
<div class='form-group'>
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstImmatriculationDate)
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div>
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 148px;">
            <input class="form-control date-picker" type="text" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="FirstImmatriculationDate" id="FirstImmatriculationDate" value="@Model.FormattedFirstImmat">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstImmatriculationDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <span id="error_msgFirstImmat" class="text-danger"> @Resources.VehicleDetails_FirstImmatError</span>
    <span id="error_msgFirstImmatTooOld" class="text-danger"> @Resources.VehicleDetails_FirstImmatTooOld</span>
    <span id="error_msgFirstImmatFormatDate" class="text-danger"> @Resources.General_FormatDate</span>
</div>
</div>
@*[...]*@
```

The DropDown on the second tab (on which the data validation must be done):

```
@*[...]*@
<div class='form-group'>
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Omnium_InnerNrDeductibleFormula)
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Omnium_InnerNrDeductibleFormula, (SelectListItem[])ViewBag.lstFormulaDeduc, new { @id = "Omnium_InnerNrDeductibleFormulaId" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Omnium_InnerNrDeductibleFormula, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <span id="error_MisingFormula" class="text-danger">@Resources.Warranty_FormulaMissing</span>
</div>
</div>
@*[...]*@
```

The code from the Forms view calling the two partial views

```
@*[...]*@
<div id="vehicleQuote" class="tab-pane in active">
<p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.VehicleDetails)</p>
<a href="#" id="btnWarrantiesPage" class="btn  btn-group-lg" title="@Resources.Warranty_NextPage" style="margin-left:61%">
    <i class="btn-label glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
    @Resources.Warranty_NextPage
</a>
</div>
<div id="warrantyQuote" class="tab-pane">
    <p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Warranty)</p>
</div>
@{
    if (Model.ResultsModel != null)
    {
        if (Model.ResultsModel.RC != null || Model.ResultsModel.errorMsg != null)
        {
            <div id="resultQuote" class="tab-pane in active">
                <p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResultsModel)</p>
            </div>
        }
    }
}

<div id="submitQuote">
    <div style="margin-left:61%">

        <button type="submit" id="btnSave" name="BtnSave" class="btn btn-palegreen" value="@Resources.General_Save">
            <i class="btn-label glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></i>
            @Resources.General_Save
        </button>
        <button type="submit" id="btnTaskTarification" name="btnTaskTarification" class="btn btn" value="@Resources.General_Save">
            <i class="btn-label glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i>
            @Resources.General_Print
        </button>
    </div>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Customers")" class="btn  btn-group-lg" title="@Resources.General_Cancel" style="margin-left:10px;">
        <i class="btn-label glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i>
        @Resources.General_Cancel
    </a>
</div>
@*[...]*@
```

The part of the model used for the DatePicker

```
public class VehicleDetails
{        
    [Display(Name = "VehicleDetails_FirstImmatriculationDate", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public DateTime? FirstImmatriculationDate { get; set; }
    //[...]
}
```

The part of the model used for the item selected in the DropDown

```
public class Warranty
{
    [Display(Name = "Warranty_Omnium_InnerNrDeductibleFormula", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public string Omnium_InnerNrDeductibleFormula { get; set; }
    //[...]
}
```

Comment: Quand c'est Renaud qui répond à ta question xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it okay for you to use jQuery?

If it is, you can simply listen to the **change** event of your dropdown, and check the date of your other input.

```
$('#Omnium_InnerNrDeductibleFormulaId').change(function(){

    var date = $('#FirstImmatriculationDate').val();

    // do whatever you want with the date value, and display an error message if necessary.

    // for example, you could put an hidden message in your DOM
    // and show/hide it depending on the result of your test :
    if(isValid(date)){
        $('#warning-message').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('#warning-message').show();
    }
}
```